# Retornar valor agrupado por data

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no *MySQL*, que armazena as confirmações dos meus clientes  no meu site, tendo como campos: `id | cod_cliente | data`, sendo a data a principal.

O que preciso é agrupar e retornar o resultado do dia.

Exemplo:

> Das 05/10/2017 | 80 confirmações
>   Das 06/10/2017 | 100 confirmações

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `DATA` FROM `confirmacao` WHERE `ID_CLI` = 27001";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `confirmacao` WHERE `ID_CLI` = 27002 GROUP BY `DATA` ORDER BY `ID` DESC";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row2["DATA"];
    echo "<br />";
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["DATA"];
    echo "<br />";
}

?>
```

Mais ele não retorna da forma correta.
como fazer isso?
Obrigado.

Comment: O que está retornando?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data, "%d/%m/%Y"), COUNT(*) FROM confirmacao WHERE cod_cliente = 27001 GROUP BY data ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row2["DATA"];
    echo "<br />";
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["DATA"];
    echo "<br />";
}

?>
```